# No Jar found in /WEB-INF/lib after deploying maven project from eclipse to wildlfy9

Tags: eclipse, maven, wildfly

I am seeing a very strange behavior of wildfly9.x. Build process goes successful. after clicking on **RUN AS -> Run on Server(WildFly9.x)**. It shows exception like **NO class def found**.
I have already added dependency in POM.xml and its scope is compile.
POM.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64 from [Module "deployment.worldportfolio.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by myself. If you want to run wildfly server from eclipse IDE so you should follow this a very simple method create lib folder in WEB-INF and place all the required Jars in the lib folder. You are done.